# Inventory Building

Tags: c++

Here is my code for adding a CD to my inventory. I add it but when I select show inventory option, it does not show up there.

```
void addCD(Inventory i) {

int isbn = readIsbn();

if ( isbn ) {
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

    cout << "CD title: ";
    cin.getline(buffer,BUF_SIZE);
    string title(buffer);

    cout << "Developer name: ";
    cin.getline(buffer,BUF_SIZE);
    string developer(buffer);

    CD new_CD(isbn,title,developer);
    i.addItem(new_CD);

}
```

Function for addItem is defined following:

```
 Inventory::addItem(Item& new_item) {

// Lookup item in inventory

ItemTable::const_iterator i = _table.find(new_item.getIsbn());


if ( i == _table.end() ) {
    Item *ptrItem = new_item.clone();
    _table[ptrItem->getIsbn()] = ptrItem;
} else {
    cout << "Warning: Item with isbn " << new_item.getIsbn()
         << " already exists" << endl;
}

}
```

There is no error but just the inventory does not show the newly added item.

Comment: How is `addCD()` called?

Comment: Please consider the `std::string` version of [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the function `void addCD(Inventory i)`, a *copy* of the argument is passed and modifying the argument `i` won't affect what the caller passed.

You should use reference to have the function modify caller's local variable.

Try using `void addCD(Inventory &i)` instead of `void addCD(Inventory i)`. (add `&`)